# How does WinForms enforce thread affinity?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I had thought it was the Single-Threaded Apartment mechanism, but [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx#Anchor_6) indicates that only applies to COM objects.

Does anyone know what *mechanism* Windows Forms uses to enforce its thread affinity?

Comment: This question may be over my head, but what do you mean by "to enforce its thread affinity"?

Comment: @adv12 for example, suppose you start a form with `Application.Run(new Form1())`, and that form has a label on it named `label1`.  Now suppose you launch a second Thread.  If the second thread tries to change `label1.Text` you'll get an error.  That's commonly called "thread affinity", you can get more info here: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: It compares the thread id of the current call with the thread id used to create the control's Window handle. If they are different, it throws an exception.

---

If you look at [the reference source for Windows.Forms.Control](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,78a957dea6cef814,references) you'll find a property called `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`:

```
    public static bool CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls {
        get { return checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls; }
        set { checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = value; }
    }
```

This is used whenever a Handle is retrieved:

```
    public IntPtr Handle {
        get {
            if (checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls &&
                !inCrossThreadSafeCall &&
                InvokeRequired) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.IllegalCrossThreadCall,
                                                                 Name));
            }

            if (!IsHandleCreated)
            {
                CreateHandle();
            }

            return HandleInternal;
        }
    }
```

Because `Handle` is accessed wherever the handle for the control is required, that's the logical place for the code to check for cross threaded calls.

It leverages the `InvokeRequired` property to see when a cross-threaded call would occur.

`InvokedRequired` is itself somewhat involved:

```
    public bool InvokeRequired {
        get {

            using (new MultithreadSafeCallScope())
            {
                HandleRef hwnd;
                if (IsHandleCreated) {
                    hwnd = new HandleRef(this, Handle);
                }
                else {
                    Control marshalingControl = FindMarshalingControl();

                    if (!marshalingControl.IsHandleCreated) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    hwnd = new HandleRef(marshalingControl, marshalingControl.Handle);
                }

                int pid;
                int hwndThread = SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
                int currentThread = SafeNativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId();
                return(hwndThread != currentThread);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice write-up. TL;DR  - compares thread id of current call with thread id used to create window.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I shall shamelessly steal your TL;DR

Comment: I had wondered if it was part of the base Control class.  Thanks very much.